# Spring multiple @Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring `@Configuration` annotation to configure my application.

Currently, I have a single `@Configuration` class where all my beans are declared. As the number of beans is growing (more than 30), I want to split it in many classes.

Some beans are using common classes (mainly utility classes) :

*Foo.class* is an utility class
*Bar.class* and *Baz.class* both use *Foo.class*

I want to have all `Foo, Bar and Baz` in three distinct `@Configuration` classes (respectively `Conf1, Conf2 and Conf3`)

The problem is that I don't have access to an instance of `Conf1` from `Conf2 and Conf3` :

**Conf1.class**

```
@Configuration 
public class Conf1 {
    @Bean
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

**Conf2.class**

```
@Configuration 
public class Conf2 {
    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setFoo(conf1.foo()); // Not possible !
        return bar;
    }
}
```

**Conf3.class**

```
@Configuration 
public class Conf3 {
    @Bean
    public Baz baz() {
        Baz baz = new Baz();
        baz.setFoo(conf1.foo()); // Not possible !
        return baz;
    }
}
```

Any idea on how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to autowire them:

```
@Configuration 
public class Conf2 {
    @Autowired
    Conf1 conf1;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can autowire beans rather than configurations:

```
@Configuration 
public class Conf2 {
    @Autowired
    Foo foo;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
@Configuration
@Import({ DataSourceConfig.class, TransactionConfig.class })
public class AppConfig extends ConfigurationSupport {
      // bean definitions here can reference bean definitions in DataSourceConfig or TransactionConfig
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed as I have multiple data sources and this was a clean way to hang them all off of the SpringWebConfig.class.

Answer (score 4):

Spring framework [chapter-5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/modularizing-configurations.html) explained it very nicely.

- **@ExternalBean**
  : One configuration class may need to reference a bean defined in another configuration class (or in XML, for that matter). The @ExternalBean annotation provides just such a mechanism. When JavaConfig encounters a method annotated as @ExternalBean, it replaces that method definition with a lookup to the enclosing bean factory for a bean with the same name as the method name
- **@Import** : 
  @Import represents JavaConfig's equivalent of XML configuration's  
  element. One configuration class can import any number of other configuration 
  classes, and their bean definitions will be processed as if locally defined
- **ConfigurationSupport** : 
  As a convenience, @Configuration classses can extend ConfigurationSupport, primarily in order to facilitate easy lookup of beans from the enclosing BeanFactory / ApplicationContext.